# Go Module Not Downloading Latest Minor Version

Tags: git, go, versioning, go-modules

I am using `go version 1.13.1`, and now I cannot update my dependecy module to the latest minor version using `go mod`, I made simple repo for learning dependency management on `github.com/clavinjune/testng` and made a project that depends on it called `moduser`.

The latest minor version of `testng` is `v1.4.0`

```
┌─[ ~/Public/testng ]─[ git:master ]
└─[ 22:09:19 ] $ git tag -l
v1.0.0
v1.1.0
v1.2.0
v1.3.0
v1.4.0
```

and `moduser` still using `v1.3.0`

```
┌─[ ~/Public/moduser ]
└─[ 22:09:06 ] $ go list -m all
moduser
github.com/clavinjune/testng v1.3.0
```

when I want to update the dependency I run this command

```
┌─[ ~/Public/moduser ]
└─[ 22:20:17 ] $ go get -v -u github.com/clavinjune/testng
┌─[ ~/Public/moduser ]
└─[ 22:20:28 ] $ go get -v -u github.com/clavinjune/testng@latest
```

But it doesn't downloading the `v1.4.0`.

Is there any wrong command that I run ?

Comment: Have you pushed tag `v1.4.0` to GitHub, or did you merely create it in your own local repository? (Note that `go list -m all` *does not* show `v1.4.0` available!)

Comment: First thing that comes to mind: git tag only shows local tags; are you sure you pushed v1.4.0 ? See also https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#daily-workflow

Comment: @torek yes i've pushed tag v1.4.0, now I realize I need to wait about 20 minutes after the new tag released. is that normal?

Comment: I'm not sure what's normal, as I have not actually started using Go modules yet.

Comment: @torek kay thanks!

Comment: @marco.m yes i've pushed it, thanks for the reading, gonna check it.

Comment: It is pushed: https://github.com/ClavinJune/testng/tree/v1.4.0 However, and I am not sure wether that matters, but note the camel case in the owner name. Never had that before.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg the I think the github username is case insensitive, because I've tried with the exact username too and it still not works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the default public proxy (`proxy.golang.org`), it has a cache on the mapping from `latest` to a specific version.

If you want to fetch a specific version, you can either pass that version explicitly to `go get`:

```
go get -d github.com/clavinjune/testng@v1.4.0
```

or temporarily set `GONOPROXY` to bypass the cache:

```
GONOPROXY=github.com/clavinjune go get -d github.com/clavinjune/testng@latest
```

Comment: Nice trick @bcmills with `GONOPROXY` env var. This does the job for me.